# Autowiring publishers/listeners with reflection in Unity Framework

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, reflection

I'm currently building an application with the Microsoft Unity Framework. I also use a simple system of message publishers/listeners inspired from MVVM light and caliburn:

**The listener interface**

```
public interface IMessageListener<T>
{

    void Handle(T Message);
}
```

**The messenger interface**

```
public interface IMessagePublisher<T>
{

    void Subscribe(IMessageListener<T> subscriber);

    void Unsubscribe(IMessageListener<T> subscriber);

    void Publish(T message);
}
```

I started to find it boring to have to inject my messengers to my listeners so they can subscribe, so I thought: "Hey, my Unity container can do that". I've coded a `UnityExtension` which autowires all resolved listener objects with their appropriate messenger(s) by using reflection. Of course, my messengers are `ContainerLifeTimeManaged`.

```
public override void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            base.PostBuildUp(context);

            foreach (Type interf in context.Existing.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType))
            {
                //If the interface is of type IMessageListener
                if (interf.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMessageListener<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                {
                    //Get the generic parameter type
                    Type genericParameter = interf.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
                    //Build the messenger type
                    Type messengerType = typeof(IMessagePublisher<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(genericParameter);
                    //Resolve the messenger
                    object messenger = _container.Resolve(messengerType);
                    //Find the subscribe method
                    MethodInfo subscribeMethod = messenger.GetType().GetMethod("Subscribe");
                    //Subscribe the listener (the array is ugly, but i just keep getting an error without it)
                    subscribeMethod.Invoke(messenger, new []{context.Existing});
                }
            }
       }
```

I've removed the exception handling on purpose. I've struggled a bit to achieve this, and I'm not sure that it's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

```
typeof(IMessageListener<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

You can simplify this to just:

```
typeof(IMessageListener<>)
```

---

Why are you combing `Where()` with an `if`? I would stick with one or the other.

---

```
interf.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault()
```

Don't use `OrDefault` when you're not going to deal with the `null`. That way, when an error happens, you're going to get a descriptive exception right away, instead of a confusing `NullReferenceException` later.

If this is part of the exception handling that you removed, then that makes it hard to review your code properly.

---

```
// […] the array is ugly, but i just keep getting an error without it
```

You have to use an array here, [`MethodInfo.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh) is not a `params` method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just learned today about the typeof(Generic<>) from another question. You are also right about the if, i'm going to get rid of it, and remove the OrDefault(). Should I edit my question ?

Comment: @IronSlug: Typically you should not modify the code in your question as it will potentially render the existing answers useless. If you have a new version of your code then best is to post a follow up review question.